# Can absolute phrase happen before main clause?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

As you may know absolute phrase (APs) can be used to describe either situation or reason (condition).
For the past, perfect participles and past participles are both good choices to use as APs.

For example:

> The sun having been risen.

But there is no real future verb in English.
So I couldn't help but think that can AP have time after main clause's time? For example: me and my friends will take exam today in 1 hour and we all here, waiting outside of the school, but one of us not here. He will be late for exam, probably because he overslept, so we have to call him and say 'come here.' So can I say to my friend "(with) him being late for exam in the end, I think we should call him."

That's my question (although I know participle clause here could be a better idea). Using with makes the verb nonfinite, so it should be also able to happen before or after from main clause, but without with the question becomes more difficult.

Comment: Can you be careful with your punctuation and formatting? It looks very messy.

Comment: And by the way, it's "absolute", not "apsolute".

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

First, absolute clausess are a feature of formal, literary English. If you use them in conversation (apart from a few fossilised phrases like "that being said") people will think you haven't been taught how to converse in English.

Secondly, *rise* is intransitive, so it cannot take a passive form, so *the sun being risen*  can only be the archaic use of *is* for the perfect of verbs of motion: pretty well obsolete in modern English. You want *the sun having risen*.

But your main point is right. The so-called "present participle" (the *-ing* form) is untensed: it is not present, or past or future, but is usually interpreted contemporaneously with the main clause.

There is a standard way of shifting it past relative to the main clause, which is to use "have" - *having been*, *having arrived* etc.

There is no equivalent standard way of shifting it into the relative future. In your example, if you insist on using an absolute clause, it would be something like *With him going to be late for the exam*.

Comment: "Going to" shouldn't be used as either participle or gerund.your last example is normally wrong. But thanks anyway

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "shouldn't be used as either participle or gerund", or on what grounds you claim that my last example is wrong. I assert (as a native English speaker) that my example is grammatical (though stilted) ,and if you insist on using an absolute clause, I think that that is about the best you can do.

Comment: please ,No offense ,if I have used offensive words.(it comes from my personality , so I'm really sorry)But some other native speaker like you told me so.he said: to express future while using participle,we should use something like planning to or attempting to + the verb we want ,not going to b'cuz it wasn't a real verb.

Comment: Here is real deal . "My roommate is moving to another city this weekend,so I need to find a new roommate to pay the rent."  Let's rewrite it with absolute constructer."My roommate moving to another city this weekend, I need to find a new roommate.....".does this sentence make sense? It has a reason absolute phrase with future expression, although I need to... Happens now not in future .

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is. A clause introduce by _with_ is **not** an absolute clause. Your friend is right that _My roommate going to move to another city..._ doesn't work; but on the other hand _With my roommate going to move to another city ..._ does. I hadn't appreciated the difference. Your last example is just about understandable but, no, it doesn't really make sense. I don't understand why you are putting so much effort into a construction which most English speakers will never use in their lives.